# Generating Perlin Noise with Xlib

Tags: c, image, xlib, screensaver, perlin-noise

I'm trying to add a cloud to an Xscreensaver.  I like the looks of a "plasma" cloud, so I'm trying to draw a perlin noise-based cloud to the background of the Xscreensaver.  I have code which creates an array that has values for the colors which make up the perlin noise.  All that I need to do is create an image from this array and set it as the background in this Xscreensaver.

How do I generate an image from this array?  I've looked into using purely Xlib, but that's a daunting task.  So if there's a way to use Cairo to generate the image from the array that would be nice.  Also, the values in the array are between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

The Cairo function for this is [cairo_image_surface_create_for_data()](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Image-Surfaces.html#cairo-image-surface-create-for-data), but getting the data into the appropriate layout for Cairo to read it can be a little daunting. The details for the in-memory image formats (described [here](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Image-Surfaces.html#cairo-format-t)) are in the `cairo.h` header file itself (in the comments), not the manual.

Another *gotcha* is: make sure to use [cairo_format_stride_for_width()](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Image-Surfaces.html#cairo-format-stride-for-width) to get the size of a row, as there may be padding requirements that you can't (don't need to) calculate yourself.

It may be tempting to try `CAIRO_FORMAT_A8` or `CAIRO_FORMAT_A1` since this is a 1-bit deep image; but I've found it easier for 1-bit images to use `CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24` and set the red green and blue values to 0 or 255. The A* formats affect the *alpha* channel, not the image data channels, so using it, you still need another source of RGB data. Opaque *nothing* is just as invisible as Transparent *nothing*. Also the arrangement of bits depends on the endianness of the underlying machine, so working directly with 32-bit values (you could use `uint32_t` if you wanted, but then your printf format specifiers get atrocious; so I stick with `long`). If you're moving whole integer values, then the endianness of the data will naturally reflect the endianness of the machine.

Here's the relevant info from `cairo.h`:

```
/**
 * cairo_format_t:
 * @CAIRO_FORMAT_INVALID: no such format exists or is supported.
 * @CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32: each pixel is a 32-bit quantity, with
 *   alpha in the upper 8 bits, then red, then green, then blue.
 *   The 32-bit quantities are stored native-endian. Pre-multiplied
 *   alpha is used. (That is, 50% transparent red is 0x80800000,
 *   not 0x80ff0000.) (Since 1.0)
 * @CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24: each pixel is a 32-bit quantity, with
 *   the upper 8 bits unused. Red, Green, and Blue are stored
 *   in the remaining 24 bits in that order. (Since 1.0)
 * @CAIRO_FORMAT_A8: each pixel is a 8-bit quantity holding
 *   an alpha value. (Since 1.0)
 * @CAIRO_FORMAT_A1: each pixel is a 1-bit quantity holding
 *   an alpha value. Pixels are packed together into 32-bit
 *   quantities. The ordering of the bits matches the
 *   endianess of the platform. On a big-endian machine, the
 *   first pixel is in the uppermost bit, on a little-endian
 *   machine the first pixel is in the least-significant bit. (Since 1.0)
 * @CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB16_565: each pixel is a 16-bit quantity
 *   with red in the upper 5 bits, then green in the middle
 *   6 bits, and blue in the lower 5 bits. (Since 1.2)
 * @CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB30: like RGB24 but with 10bpc. (Since 1.12)
 *
 * #cairo_format_t is used to identify the memory format of
 * image data.
 *
 * New entries may be added in future versions.
 *
 * Since: 1.0
 **/
typedef enum _cairo_format {
    CAIRO_FORMAT_INVALID   = -1,
    CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32    = 0,
    CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24     = 1,
    CAIRO_FORMAT_A8        = 2,
    CAIRO_FORMAT_A1        = 3,
    CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB16_565 = 4,
    CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB30     = 5
} cairo_format_t;
```

My [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10588779/733077) in the other answer is a really bad example. But it's that way because I couldn't find any example at all when I wrote it, so ... *ex nihilo nihil*. It tries to pack the appropriate data array using source data that is known to be big-endian, and may be 1-bit, 2-bit, 4-bit or 8-bits deep. Egad, it even has the innocent little statement

```
         run(st);
```

which invokes the whole interpreter recursively, which was hell to get the `error` mechanism to `longjmp` to the *correct* instance of the interpreter. It's a really terrible example of using `cairo_image_surface_create_for_data()`. But ... somebody show me a better one. Please!

---

Here's a write-up of a simpler example. I haven't tested it, but it's a simpler way of doing what you need, I think.

```
#include <stdint.h> /* uint32_t */

uint32_t datasamp(double d) { // convert floating point to rgb-byte-field integer
    uint32_t u;
    u = d * 255; // [0.0 .. 1.0] -> [0 .. 255] 
    return u<<16 | u<<8 | u; // r = g = b = u  0x00rrggbb 
}

// samp is a 2D double array
// double samp[hgt][wid];    
uint32_t *imagedata(int wid, int hgt, double *samp){ 
    int stride; 
    uint32_t *data;
    int i,j;
    stride = cairo_format_stride_for_width(CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24, wid);
    data = malloc(stride*hgt*sizeof(uint32_t));  //use stride instead of width
    for (i=0; i < hgt; i++) {
        for (j=0; j < wid; j++) {
            data[i*stride + j] =    // use stride for data row width
                datasamp(samp[i*wid + j]);  // use wid as normal for source array
        }       
    }
    return data;
}
```

The returned data will be appropriate to pass to `cairo_image_surface_create_for_data`. The important thing is to use `stride` for the row width, even if the source data is arranged differently (here it's only `wid` wide).

Oh, and it's a sort-of reverse-polish "apps Hungarian" that I'm using for a naming convention here. So `imagedata` means "image <-- data". `datasamp` means "data <-- samp".

Comment: I've also posted my code for using this in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10588779/733077). But it's not clean at all. I had a lot of false starts and dead-ends (most of which are still present in the comments).

Comment: Yeah, I warned you. Looks like it doesn't work quite right for 4-bit images, too. It'll get rewritten when my new program gets to that point.

Comment: I'm just wondering which code is used to set the structure of the image in memory.  For instance, how do you exactly set the `data` variable in the `drawimage()` function?

Comment: I think I could've done that a little simpler. I used `unsigned long *ldata = data;` and then store the 32-bit longs (`long` is guaranteed by the C standard to be at least 32-bits) through the `ldata` pointer. I probably could've just used `unsigned long data[...];` and then cast the pointer to `(unsigned char *)` in the call. ... I don't remember why I multiplied the data size by 4, it looks unnecessary to me now.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit of a noob here.  You say you store the "32-bit longs through the `ldata` pointer".  Is this just one big variable, or an array?

Comment: It's an array. But it can be accessed as bytes through `data` or as ints through `ldata`.

Comment: Bytes, huh?  The perlin Noise array I generate has values for the colors.  Could I some how manipulate the `data` variable to set the color values?  Or is that something else entirely?

Comment: I've added a simpler example. But my X skills are a little rusty, so it'll take a little more time for me to flesh-out a complete example.

Comment: Thank you for your time, luser droog.

Answer (score 0):

Rummaging around in old directories, I found an example using `CAIRO_FORMAT_A1` and `cairo_mask_surface` that might be closer to what you want than the other examples (and belies some of my assertions above). And this one is complete. Compile with this makefile

```
CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/cairo #-Wa,-alh
LDLIBS=-lcairo
```

using `make mask`

```
/* mask.c test program for cairo bit mask
   makes a big blue turkey from the Postscript manual */
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <cairo.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <cairo-xlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

enum { little, big } endian = little;

unsigned char reversebits (unsigned char b) {
    return (b & 0x01? 0x80: 0)
        |  (b & 0x02? 0x40: 0)
        |  (b & 0x04? 0x20: 0)
        |  (b & 0x08? 0x10: 0)
        |  (b & 0x10? 0x08: 0)
        |  (b & 0x20? 0x04: 0)
        |  (b & 0x40? 0x02: 0)
        |  (b & 0x80? 0x01: 0)
        ;
}

void paintmask(cairo_t *cr, unsigned char *samp, int w, int h) {
    int span; /* width in bytes */
    int stride; /* width in words */
    cairo_surface_t *mask;
    unsigned char *data;
    int i,j,k;
    uint32_t u;

    stride = cairo_format_stride_for_width(CAIRO_FORMAT_A1, w);
    /* stride = (w/32) + (w%32 ? 1 : 0) */
    span = w/8 + (w%8? 1: 0);
    printf("stride = %d\n", stride);
    data = malloc(h * stride);

    /* convert bytes to 32bit quantities matching
       endianness of the machine */
    /* each row */
    for (i = 0; i < h; i++) {

        /* each 32bit int in row */
        for (j = 0; j < stride/4; j++) {
            u = 0; /* zero the word */

            /* each 8bit byte in 32bit int from samples */
            for (k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                uint8_t b;

                u <<= 8;

                if (j*4+k < span) {

                    /* postscript input is always big-endian */
                    /* so grab most-significant byte */
                    b = samp[i*span + j*4 + k];

                    if (endian == little) {
                        //b = samp[i*span + j*4 + (4-1-k)];
                        b = reversebits(b);
                    }

                    u |= b;
                }
                //printf("%X\n", u);
            } /* k */

            printf("%08X\n", u);
            *((uint32_t *)(data + i*stride + j)) = u;

        } /* j */
    } /* i */

    mask = cairo_image_surface_create_for_data(data, CAIRO_FORMAT_A1, w, h, stride);
    cairo_mask_surface(cr, mask, 0, 0);
}



int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int width = 480;
    int height = 460;
    Display *dis;
    int scr;
    int depth;
    Visual *vis;
    XSetWindowAttributes attr;
    unsigned long attrmask;
    Window win;
    cairo_surface_t *surface;
    cairo_t *cr;

    dis = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    scr = DefaultScreen(dis);
    depth = DefaultDepth(dis, scr);
    vis = DefaultVisual(dis, scr);
    attr.background_pixel = WhitePixel(dis, scr);
    attr.border_pixel = BlackPixel(dis, scr);
    attr.event_mask = ExposureMask | StructureNotifyMask | ButtonPressMask;
    attrmask = CWColormap | CWBackPixel | CWBorderPixel | CWEventMask;
    win = XCreateWindow(dis, RootWindow(dis, scr),
            200, 10, //pos
            width, height, 5, //width height border
            depth,
            InputOutput,
            vis,
            attrmask, &attr);
    XMapWindow(dis, win);
    surface = cairo_xlib_surface_create(dis, win, vis, width, height);
    cr = cairo_create(surface);
    cairo_scale(cr, 10, 10);

    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 1);

    {

        unsigned char samp[] = {
            0x00, 0x3B, 0x00,
            0x00, 0x27, 0x00,
            0x00, 0x24, 0x80,
            0x0E, 0x49, 0x40,
            0x11, 0x49, 0x20,

            0x14, 0xB2, 0x20,
            0x3C, 0xB6, 0x50,
            0x75, 0xFE, 0x88,
            0x17, 0xFF, 0x8C,
            0x17, 0x5F, 0x14,

            0x1C, 0x07, 0xE2,
            0x38, 0x03, 0xC4,
            0x70, 0x31, 0x82,
            0xF8, 0xED, 0xFC,
            0xB2, 0xBB, 0xC2,

            0xBB, 0x6F, 0x84,
            0x31, 0xBF, 0xC2,
            0x18, 0xEA, 0x3C,
            0x0E, 0x3E, 0x00,
            0x07, 0xFC, 0x00,

            0x03, 0xF8, 0x00,
            0x1E, 0x18, 0x00,
            0x1F, 0xF8, 0x00 };

/*
 */

        unsigned char samp2[] = {
            0x00, 0x3B, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3B, 0x00,
            0x00, 0x27, 0x00, 0x00, 0x27, 0x00,
            0x00, 0x24, 0x80, 0x00, 0x24, 0x80,
            0x0E, 0x49, 0x40, 0x0E, 0x49, 0x40,
            0x11, 0x49, 0x20, 0x11, 0x49, 0x20,

            0x14, 0xB2, 0x20, 0x14, 0xB2, 0x20,
            0x3C, 0xB6, 0x50, 0x3C, 0xB6, 0x50,
            0x75, 0xFE, 0x88, 0x75, 0xFE, 0x88,
            0x17, 0xFF, 0x8C, 0x17, 0xFF, 0x8C,
            0x17, 0x5F, 0x14, 0x17, 0x5F, 0x14,

            0x1C, 0x07, 0xE2, 0x1C, 0x07, 0xE2,
            0x38, 0x03, 0xC4, 0x38, 0x03, 0xC4,
            0x70, 0x31, 0x82, 0x70, 0x31, 0x82,
            0xF8, 0xED, 0xFC, 0xF8, 0xED, 0xFC,
            0xB2, 0xBB, 0xC2, 0xB2, 0xBB, 0xC2,

            0xBB, 0x6F, 0x84, 0xBB, 0x6F, 0x84,
            0x31, 0xBF, 0xC2, 0x31, 0xBF, 0xC2,
            0x18, 0xEA, 0x3C, 0x18, 0xEA, 0x3C,
            0x0E, 0x3E, 0x00, 0x0E, 0x3E, 0x00,
            0x07, 0xFC, 0x00, 0x07, 0xFC, 0x00,

            0x03, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x03, 0xF8, 0x00,
            0x1E, 0x18, 0x00, 0x1E, 0x18, 0x00,
            0x1F, 0xF8, 0x00, 0x1F, 0xF8, 0x00 };

        //paintmask(cr, samp, 24, 23);
        paintmask(cr, samp2, 48, 23);
        XFlush(dis);
    }
    sleep(20);

    cairo_destroy(cr);
    cairo_surface_destroy(surface);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have tried using some of your code in order to draw some shapes with Cairo instead of generating a Perlin Noise.  However, that doesn't work, either.  I can't get it to [draw to the screen](http://pastebin.com/svb2SzCa).  I declared the surface at lines 624-626 and set other Cairo things at lines 562-593, but none of that code's working.

Comment: Sometimes you have to flush the output. [cairo_surface_flush](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-cairo-surface-t.html#cairo-surface-flush), [XFlush](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xflush).

Comment: I don't know what's in "screenhack.h". Maybe it defines a surface you should use?

Comment: You mean flush the Cairo output, or the output of the xscreenaver code? I can't call XFlush because the xscreensaver's parent code is responsible for that. Edit: I shall look in that header file.

Comment: I found it, I think. https://github.com/danfuzz/xscreensaver/blob/master/hacks/screenhack.c  Looks like it doesn't call `XFlush`, so I still recommend you try that (at the end of the draw function).

Comment: It says in the provided README.hacking file included with the xscreensavers to not call XFlush().  Still, I shall try using cairo_surface_flush().  Though I wonder why I can't affect the `flake->DB.b` pixmap with Cairo?